# Create one controller's method with two routings - distinguish called route

Tags: php, routes, annotations, symfony-2.1

I have following `@Route` annottations for my Controller's method:

```
/**
 * @Route("/{id}/edit", name="section_edit")
 * @Route("/{id}/duplicate", name="section_duplicate")
 * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
 * @Template
 */
public function editAction(Request $request, $id)
{
}
```

Is it possible to discover, which route was called ? `edit` or `duplicate` ?

I did it because the logic for both routes is simmilar. I can create two actions which will call the same method with specified parameter, but I wonder if it is possible to do it with one method and define some `$method` parameter with `edit`/`duplicate` value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is quite simple - adding `defaults` with no relation to the pattern - as below:

```
/**
 * @Route("/{id}/edit", name="section_edit", defaults={"method" : "edit"})
 * @Route("/{id}/duplicate", name="section_duplicate", defaults={"method" : "duplicate"})
 * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
 * @Template
 */
public function editAction(Request $request, $id, $method)
{
    var_dump($method); // gives `edit` or `duplicate`
}
```